# How can I fix the design for different versions on the same device

Tags: responsive-design, react-native

On an iPhone5s, version 8.4 my design looks fine.  When I upgrade the version to 9.1 on the same device I get a design problem. How can I maintain a consistent design across different versions and different devices?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to use `flex` to create a responsive design and test it across a number of devices and versions to make sure it remains consistent.

If you run into specific issues I would set up specific components that give you the style of text you want (ie a `Title` component, a `content` component, a `subtitle` component) and use [this plugin](https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-native-device) to detect the device and version and use it to configure those components' styles.